# Cocos2d-x game development for Microsoft Surface

Tags: windows, cocos2d-iphone, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, windows-rt

I have a little question.

Can I develop for the Microsoft's Surface (Windows RT and Windows 8 Pro) tablet with Cocos2d-x?

In that case, which version of Cocos2d-x I will need to use? Because there a lot of branches of the Cocos source.

And, Can I use the same code for Surface and for Windows Phone 8?

Thanks in advance!

Sorry for my beginner's English, I'm learning =)

**EDIT:**

Digging a bit deeper in the Cocos2d-X documentation, I see the HTML5 branch.

Is it viable develop a game with that technology and port the game to iOS, Android and Windows using a WebView, UIWebView and the Windows's equivalent?

Comment: interesting question. i'm in the same situation, let me know if you find something out!

Comment: I haven't response yet. I did the same question in the Cocos2d-x forum, but no answer yet. I think that Cocos2d-5 (HTML5) is the answer for non heavy games with small requirements. Also, the actual W8 branch is based in Cocos2d-x 1.x, so it's a bit older and non compatible with the 2.x branch.

I will use a webview in Android, an UIWebView in iOS and the equivalent for W8 for using the same code for the 3 platforms, and also if I want, I can port to another platforms.

Comment: Regarding Cocos2d-html5, it runs your code scripted to native calls when running on iOS or Android. No need for a UIWebView and get a performance hit. There is quite a lot regarding the JS bindings here: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/wiki/cocos2d-and-JavaScript

For WinRT there isn't a release yet. However, you can use Cocos2d-X on top of Marmalade SDK, which is planned to have a WinRT release early 2013 (https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmaladesdk/features/take-apps-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can develop for Windows 8 using Cocos2d-X Windows 8 version.
Sometime in the feature the will merge it with the main version,
but currently you'll have to use the Windows 8 branch. Please not that it uses the old Cocos2d-x API.

I've successfully released my game "Noogra Nuts" using Cocos2d-x for Windows 8 and it works well.

Comment: Hi Oren! How are you? Thanks for the response! But I have a question about that. When you talks about Windows 8, you refer to W8 for PC (x86 & x64), WP8 (ARM) or WinRT (Microsoft Surface)? Because I wanna develop a game for the Microsoft Surface, and in my country only sells the ARM model with WinRT, which branch I have to use for develop to this platform? 
Also, It's possible develop at the same time for W8 PC, WP8 and WinRT?
In another topic, congratulations for your game, it's awsome! and really addicting!!! :)

Thanks for your help, and again, sorry for my bad English, I'm learning.

Comment: Yes, you can compile the Windows 8 Cocos2d-x branch to x86, x64 or ARM.
It is just a matter of choosing what to configuration to build.
When I submitted my game I've submitted 3 binary files: x86, x64 and ARM.

Comment: @OrenBengigi do you mind telling me which branch of cocos2d-x-windows-8 you used? Thanks